# How to read an arbitrary process's stdout pipe in Linux?

Tags: pipe, stdout

I have a child process launched via Supervisor that's somehow become disconnnected from its parent and is running but not outputting to the parent's log file anymore.

However, it's still running, and presumably is still writing to its stdout. How do I read this?

I've found the pid, and if I check `/proc/$pid/fd` I get:

```
$ sudo ls -lah /proc/$pid/fd
total 0
dr-x------ 2 root root  0 Mar  5 21:01 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root  0 Mar  5 21:01 ..
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Mar  5 21:01 0 -> 'pipe:[83894068]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  5 21:01 1 -> 'pipe:[83894069]'
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Mar  5 21:01 2 -> 'pipe:[83894070]'
```

How do I access the output pipe and read it from `tail` or some other process to read its output?

Comment: Presumably there's still at least one process at the other end or it would get a SIGPIPE when it tries to write there. What's the output of `lsof -w +E -p "$pid" -ad 0-2`?

Comment: If the processes at the other end are in some sort of frozen state, you should be able to do `cat "/proc/$pid/fd/1"` to read what `$pid` writes there (that in effect hijacks the data which means the other process won't see it).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The output of `lsof...` is nothing. The `cat...` command also outputs nothing, although that could just be due to the process having very infrequent output.

Comment: that must be run as root and should give you the same thing as your `ls` command with more information (assuming you have a reasonably recent version of `lsof` and you're on a Linux-based system)